# asp:button works locally but no on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, local, html

I have 4 asp:buttons on my web page. One of them works correctly the other three do not. The form on my web page is a simple encryption application. I am new to asp.net so any help would be greatly appreciated. The entire site works correctly locally of course but when uploaded on to the server 3 buttons don't work. I might be over looking something obvious but the sample code is below:

*Only the Encrypt button works. 
Generic error code for other buttons: 
ScriptResource.axd:5 Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    Enter Password: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" MaxLength="15" CssClass="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" CssClass="Button" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload File" CssClass="Button" CausesValidation="False" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <br />
    Enter Text:
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="TestStyle"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="TestStyle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />--%>
    <asp:Button  ID="Encrypt" OnClick="EncryptBT_Click" runat="server" CssClass="Button"  CausesValidation="False" Text="Encrypt"></asp:Button>
    <asp:Button  ID="Decrypt" OnClick="DecryptBT_Click" runat="server"  CssClass="Button" CausesValidation="False" Text="Decrypt"></asp:Button>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Save Encrypted Text File</legend>File name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="textboxName" runat="server" Width="93px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="buttonSave" runat="server" Text="Save As" CssClass="Button" Width="66px" OnClick="Save_Click" /></fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check using developer Tools whether buttons are on the page or not.
Also, check whether their onClick method has been implemented or not in code -behind.

Comment: I reviewed the developers tools extensively and the buttons are on the page. I'm confused as to why the encrypt button would work but not the decrypt button. Everything works fine locally but when I published my site that button won't work.